# http compression with htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have the following setup - it may seem a bit strange, but the environment forces me to redirect so much:

- .htaccess file:

  ```
  <ifModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript font/ttf font/woff image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  </ifModule>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^tools\.js$ tools.php [NC]
  ```
- the file tools.php:

  ```
  <?php 
  require ('javascript.php');
  ```
- the file javascript.php:

  ```
  <?php
  header('Content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8;'); 
  // etc.
  ?>window.onpagehide = function(e) {document.getElementById('someElement').style.display = 'none';};
  var x = '';
  //etc.
  ```

I want the file ("http://example.com/tools.js") to be gzipped (deflated) when served by Apache. It doesn't do it. It does correctly deflate a normal css file in that same folder, though.

What do I need to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your PHP config (php.ini), to make sure it has the following line:

```
zlib.output_compression=On
```

Source: [How to enable GZip compression in XAMPP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993320/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-in-xampp-server#answer-19751491)

Comment: Thanks a huge lot, @Jon! I passed this on to my webhoster, and it did the trick.